# Cannot generate source files from XSD files using Maven?

Tags: maven, soap, wsdl, soap-client, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have this [wsdl schema](https://horizonws.gothiagroup.com/AFSServices/AFSService.svc?wsdl). I need to generate source code files from that WSDL schema. I tried many many different things, but couldn't get to generate Java stubs. In this post I'll try to outline only the last and most relevant approach I took. Also, I will be pointing out my suspicions where might be the problem and I'll post console error I received. There is the link to the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/MiljanGitHub/generate-stubs-from-xsd)(It is simple Maven project, in Spring Tools Suite, with only one starter class and no settings what so ever. I used Java 1.8).

**Approach**

My very first attempt was to use `SOAP UI` tool, and from link above generated `*.xsd` files using that tool. After successfully created those files, I placed them in `src/main/resources/arvatoprod` folder within Maven project. Then I created following `pom.xml` (omitted irrelevant dependencies) within Maven project.

```
    <build>
        <finalName>Fleaty</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.zesium.arvato</generatePackage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/arvatoprod</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Before that I actually, as I always do, did `Maven-clean` command. Messages I got from the console, after `Maven generate-sources` command, are as follows (I'll paste entire message and explain my take on key lines):

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/Miljan/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd{377,94}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd; lineNumber: 377; columnNumber: 94; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.generateCode(XJC23Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd{328,106}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd; lineNumber: 328; columnNumber: 106; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.generateCode(XJC23Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute(XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.520 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-22T20:08:48+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate (default) on project Fleaty: Failed to compile input schema(s)! Error messages should have been provided. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**First section of error above:**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/Miljan/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I'm not exactly sure what this message is supposed to tell me. In any case, I've tried deleting the folder `2.3.0` at the location `/C:/Users/Miljan/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/` since on that location I have got bunch of other versions/folders `2.3.1`, `2.3.4`. Every time I hit `Maven generate-sources`, that folder `2.3.0` reappears. The content of that folder can be se on the image bellow:

[image: Content of jaxb 2.3.0]

**Second section of the error above**

The message above also contains these four lines:

```
ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd{377,94}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd; lineNumber: 377; columnNumber: 94; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
```

and

```
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd{328,106}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Miljan/Desktop/CommitRevertGeneratedFromXsdWorkspaceArvoProd/Fleaty/src/main/resources/arvatoprod/AFSService_1.xsd; lineNumber: 328; columnNumber: 106; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
```

So the `wsimport` tool (which is probably use by `jax2b-maven-plugin` to generate stubs) cannot build those Java classes, since there is some kind of naming error. If I'm correct, essentially this is compile error and for some reason `wsimport`  tool (or the plugin) cannot resolve it.

I was not lazy, so I opened the `xsd` file which is referred in the error, `AFSService_1.xsd`. This is how lines `328` and `377` look like:

Line `328`:

```
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:AFSInvoiceAccountInfo"/>
```

Line `377`:

```
  <xs:element name="AFSInvoiceAccountInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:AFSInvoiceAccountInfo"/>
```

I did my research and what people are doing something called `binding` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html)). Essentially, it is possible to change the naming of a method, data type etc. Now, I'm not super well versed with `XSD`, `WSDL`s and generally with `JAXB` architecture. I do know the basic terminology (what are `xml namespaces`, `xsd schemas`, what are `SAX` and `DOM` parsers, `XPath`, `XQuery`, I used all of those).

What I'm not sure is whether I'm supposed to write those bindings, that is my last step to take, or I just need to configure something on my machine/project to make those stubs?

Comment: Boath approaches look legit to me. Choose one and I'll help you making it work.

Comment: I already tested those approaches, that's how I got errors...I mean, I'm fine with any approache, as long as it producing those .class files :) I am struggling for few days now with this...

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47952373 the two error messages indicate that there seems to be a conflicting entity between the wsdl referred in the question and something else in your project.

Comment: @cooltea Hi cooltea :) Thank you so much for helping out, in couple hours I'll update my question and post link to the GitHub. Thanks again.

Comment: @lexicore Sir, If you find some time I'll be more then grateful for your opinion :) Thank you.

Comment: @Miljan Thanks for revisiting the question: I was able to replicate the issue and am finalizing my answer. In short: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438253/618156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the full picture in the question!
The following answer is pretty much the one given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438253/618156

The issue is mainly due to XJC having trouble with `AccountInfo` and `AFSInvoiceAccountInfo` (according to the answer linked above).

So it seems that one needs to discern them manually:

You need the following `bindings.xjb` file in `src/main/resources` (will be found automatically by the `maven-xjb2-plugin`):

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="1.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://clienttesthorizon.horizonafs.com/AFSServices/AFSService.svc?xsd=xsd2">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='AFSInvoiceAccountInfo']">
            <jaxb:factoryMethod name="AFSInvoiceAccountInfo"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='AccountInfo']">
            <jaxb:factoryMethod name="AccountInfo"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

... which worked for me with the following configuration for the `maven-xjb2-plugin` in your `pom.xml` (removed everything that I deemed unnecessary for my testing, it's pretty close to what you originally posted in the question):

```
<project...>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>https://clienttesthorizon.horizonafs.com/AFSServices/AFSService.svc?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ... -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```